# Product id #s changed after import

Tags: product, import

I'm importing products from 1.7 into 1.9 but the product id #s have changed. How do I fix this?

Comment: From csv ? in csv check entity_id column because csv use sku

Comment: is it a new version of 1.9 or are you importing to an existing version?

Comment: ver. 1.9.1.0 @brentwpeterson

Comment: @yldziner so you have an existing version of 1.9.1 with orders, products and customers that you already have in production... is this correct?

Comment: @brentwpeterson The 1.9 install is dev mode. I imported the products from the LIVE 1.7 site and the product id #s changed. I tried to change the entity_id in the database but then the product's html page gets a 404 error, so that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You just don't change the product id's. Those are `PRIMARY KEY` values from the Magento database.

If you hardcoded product id's somewhere in the code, change it to SKU.